# Quarkus with Maven or Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, quarkus

We are recently working on converting gradle based SpringBoot projects in to Quarkus. I am debating whether I should continue to use gradle or switch to maven. Gradle allows custom dependency scopes, which provides better-modeled and faster builds but not sure these statement is still valid in the Quarkus world.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either Gradle or Maven with Quarkus. According to the Quarkus docs, you can use either tool "to create a new project, add or remove extensions, launch development mode, debug your application, and build your application into a jar, native executable, or container-friendly executable."  See https://quarkus.io/guides/gradle-tooling and https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling